# please i try to know wich library i need ti handel NVIC and what i should do to declare NVIC_InitStructure

Tags: c, embedded, stm32f1

I am working on STM32F103 and the aim is to implement some libraries.

When I declare NVIC_InitStructure it's underlined in red which means that Eclipse do not recognize it. I did declare before use it : `NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;` but it's red undelined.

Maybe there a library to include before use that?

```
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;           

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;              
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;                 

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = CAN1_RX0_INTERRUPTS;                                                                             
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);                                 
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = CAN1_TX_INTERRUPTS;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NVIC_InitTypeDef struct` is defined in a header file called `misc.h` in the STM32 standard peripheral library. So just include that in your source file.

```c
#include "misc.h"
```

To [quote](https://github.com/nematix/stm32f10x-stdperiph-lib/blob/master/Libraries/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Driver/inc/misc.h):

> This file contains all the functions prototypes for the miscellaneous firmware library functions (add-on to CMSIS functions).

Comment: Or `#include <stm32f30x_misc.h>` for me.

Comment: SPL is dead and should not be adviced for any new designs